# Анимация перехода между активностями

Tags: android

Как убрать стандартную анимацию перехода между активностями?

@null

Не помогает. Приложение вылетает.

Comment: intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)

Comment: Чтобы добавить флаг намерению, нужно заменить startActivity(new Intent(getActivity().this, TestActivity.class)); на Intent bla = new Intent(getActivity().this, TestActivity); intent.addFlags (FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION); startActivity(bla); ?

Comment: windowAnimationStyle не работает?

Comment: @СергейГрушин все верно